# PHP how to fetch data from config catalog? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to fetch data from config/mail - specific I need address:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'contact@agency'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'agency'),
],
```

I can't get there from my Controller. I tryed do like this:

```
$adres = config/mail['from.address']
```

But it doesn't work. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Reading documentation helps https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#accessing-configuration-values

Answer (score 1):

there's a function for that see:

[Laravel accessing configuration values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)

So it will be something like this

```
$adres= config('mail.from.address');
```

Comment: I think you should've just commented on the OP and OP should delete the post; it adds no value; its all mentioned in documentation.

Comment: Should it add value ? if it helps him.